# Unable to find devenv in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm running a bat file to build cppunit. However, when I run it I get many errors related to devenv not being a command, even though it is. Surely enough, I did a quick search using 'where' and it wasn't able to find the executable.

Here is an example of the errpr from the bat file.

> devenv  Build2010.sln /build "Release|Win32"
>   'devenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

So my question is "Should I download the missing devenv.exe and if so where?"

Comment: I already verified that the bin folder of the VS2010 was already part of the PATH env variable. And even if it was, the executable isn't even in the folder.

Comment: And, did you see a `devenv.exe` in that `bin` folder?

Comment: devenv is not actually located in a bin folder.  it is located inside intside `Common7\IDE`.  Where are you expecting to find it?

Comment: I'm using 'where' on 'c:\' and I still cannot find it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how it goes;

1. right click on Computer
2. Properties
3. Advanced System Settings
4. Environment Variables
5. Find Path in System Variables section
6. Edit
7. In your computer you should find the path to **devenv.com** or **devenv.exe**. For instance mine is : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE
8. Copy and paste this path to Path in System Variables section. (**Don't forget ";" after the previous one**)
9. Save and restart the command line

Comment: And remember double quotes if your path has spaces

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `devenv` program simply isn't on your path.  It can generally be located in the following directory

```
%VS100COMNTOOLS%\..\IDE\devenv.com
```

Try replacing `devenv` in your bat file with the above text and that should fix the problem.

Note that I intentionally used `.com` above instead of `.exe`.  Visual Studio is intended to be run from the command line with `devenv.com`